# Why am I getting error "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am getting an error that says "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function" however there is a list variable in my state which is binded so I am not sure why the map function is not working.

```
      getList(){
        console.log("FUNCTION CALLED");
        axios.get("/api/mentorRequests")
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Logging results", result);
          this.setState({users: result});
        })
      }
      render() {
        console.log("USERS", this.state.users);
        return (
          <div className="">
               {this.state.users.map((user) => 
                <div>
                  {user.displayName}
                </div>
              )}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: Please provide more information. map() is an array method, so the possible issue is your users state is not an array. try to initialize users state with an empty array and check the result you get from getList() is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check and see if the response you are getting is an array because .map is array function you cant use it on something else so it'll give you TypeError because type of the object you are trying to use .map is not right.

Answer (score 2):

You might forget to initialize `state.users` with an empty array.

```js
this.state = {
  users: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following:

```
getList() {
   console.log("FUNCTION CALLED");
   axios.get("/api/mentorRequests")
   .then((result) => {
      console.log("Logging results", result);
      this.setState({users: result});
   })
}
render() {
   console.log("USERS", this.state.users);
   return (
     <div className="">
        {this.state.users && this.state.users.map((user) => 
            <div>
               {user.displayName}
            </div>
        )}
     </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My function getList() was returning a json object and I was setting the array in my state to the json object so there was a type mismatch. Thanks to everyone who helped.